# Why does Nonnegativity matter in Integral?

Tags: integration

In integration, we first see a nonnegative function in some theorems, e.g., monotonicity and linearity of integrable function, and later we can see the case of a general function. Still, I can't clearly catch why nonnegativity has to be a matter. Does it have any relation to integrability, i.e., less than infinity?

Comment: In many cases we want that integral produces non-negative values for non-negative functions. This corresponds to the *positivity* of the ambient measure, and this property is crucial when reconstructing the measure from the integration functional (e.g. see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)).

Comment: @ sos440  Thanks! In order to make integral positive is clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to think about this. Here is one.

There are two "integrable" notions. There is the weak notion, which is "the integral can be defined", and there is the strong notion, which is "the integral is a finite number". In the Lebesgue theory, a measurable function which takes on one sign is always integrable in the weak sense, but a measurable function which takes on both signs may not be (because the integrals of the positive and negative parts might both be infinity). So restricting attention to nonnegative measurable functions allows us to ignore the possibility that a function is not even integrable in the weak sense. We deal with that at the end, when we try to subtract the integral of the negative part from the integral of the positive part.

A warning: my terminology here is not standard.

Short version: assuming your function takes on one sign allows you to dodge $\infty-\infty$ issues.

Comment: I appreciate your best answer. It is really simple and intuitive.